# JS with Flow types - pass Generic from outer to innerscope of a curried function

Tags: generics, flowtype, currying

Is there a way to pass the outer `Key` type to the inner `Key` and inner function's argument?

I need all these types to be the same.

```js
function getAudienceHelper<Key>(defintions: { [Key]: string }) {
  return function<Key>(
    prioritisedAudiences: Key[],
    ...

  ) {
      ...
  }
}
```

So that when I call `getAudienceHelper`, I pass in a string enum type `AudienceKey` and it flows right through to the other functions in my [code](https://flow.org/try/#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-wrD6Jv3o7WA+wQ6v-LXFTnMAPzYVh2DvUNH0NTYTWNcFgGAMBxCOVQUzASE-UmNQwBWNZ1VQeCwEEXkSDgNZKGiXkYDIe0wHQAALfAEFiWpBDAOjYleMBsFiJhwz5E4VXiGBeUmKjKHwAA2AAWfCEIACUQMBqELQiF1iGj6PwNoWAQRNbRZCFfXVAMDifOTcBgPBlGjTBMTLCtySrGtMDrUwCUZbYOBNM0jzQozoRs2N933cCzxTJ900zbM305KBE1oVMZ1xVs3I0EtgsDdA6FidBYgAGWY3BlAULZAPOS5k2aFlUvULN53YaY5kWHClBghRyquG4qoxDtgr5Tp1ji5QEqfTyYr6nyLQ65N7jWJ5XnWRdDRXGpAsG+LwsNDd7J3TY9z6xkwAsm5eoOvZDwtTLstygrMCKrZxrOsBbk0yh-17QDMuDe8w02pLbwTJNzzTDcPyYbbiW3F09ses7bmU9BqDo9ZSpfMBRjLFN9r6qx9wsb0MBwfAn2u2JmnEOxVXUergm5KnWQpygqY3a48rgWJyA0BRRTgJ5cBU-HrAIpE6OuPkWFiA8iCYWJRRgfB0LwgixMkqSwAAWkI6IZlo5RMHc9A4EUA5aIYsokvZNogMoYduN4-iumcHp3A8WSwBVsAAHY1c18R5RgU2Ff8yZDYPc0TkluUFXwDpA8UWIZi0onDKhSZpdwJ8CCY-YbI3RmqdJvPKbIdQnJpBR85L0nGSCzlBKIYTK9LxDi-UQu40BsKSCbivW-SzKnwUNbHtC37EpxSKaizdL9yGkbDVZGqYLKi5OtwbqYyCAfDXMyyiuaJ8MXWMI9Cd3oPE2dK57+nFF4bdRm28Q1SfJ1vSfnLyTQIuhSIlsBRV9HRMAsclBECgJ0ABvJWLKX2EBHmRBeSaVokTJg1h9xdl5KPZM498wKCiiKCUUoZT2iaADU8Y8m7GhNBg426Am7V3YO9WgrJGgbjpiXXuTMS4tmeHAMgw40YcEFiabeSU1pYOBklcGaENo4KSNBOGr0mHPnnDcOhb8cqxGURuCRKZKEKIOvDHKSMUbbDRlAeUNwqH7gIm4dS+BJqUDQZyRxtNW4KAxpDFMLMmBsw5gSBQFiYAnUFhYIAA)

```js
type AudienceDefs = { 
  AUDIENCE_1: string,
  AUDIENCE_2: string
}

const AUDIENCE_DEFS: AudienceDefs = { 
  AUDIENCE_1: 'audience_1'
  AUDIENCE_2: 'audience_2'
}

type AudienceKey = $Keys<typeof Audience>;

getAudienceHelper<AudienceKey>(AUDIENCE_DEFS)
```

I'm trying to solve the types and wondering if I have over-typed my functions. How strict does it need to be? Basically, I want to ensure that whatever I put in - AudienceKey - is the same type I get back from my `getAudienceHelper`. From the flow try code, `getAudienceHelper` has to run two other functions internally to return a value of the same type.

Comment: take a different name or assign to a different name.

Comment: It is a bit not clear what are you trying to achieve. Is this what you're looking for? https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHEUCmAnAYua8wA8A0mgJ4B8AFAB4BciA3ogNomkC69AzlBjGAHNEAXwCUjAFCJEUxKEiwEifmEw4F+SqXptm7UQ2GzZGNFBAYkKtbkVhKAeQBGAKzTQAdAGsyXGqNEAbgkjaQkoUgAHNEQAQRAAExg0SDQAETRgLkQAXkYZaViAVTSASQBRADkAYXKAfQBGbl5+AQAaWWKyqtq6gCZmvkEQiQkIBB44koqa+rTyrABleniklIh0zOy8pk7pnvqmxAByBuOOwv3Z-vpjvuOR8KiY1eTUtlzEABI2LgII6JwYBTbrXeZLcjBCQodDYWz4AivdZoNhULozXrgxaiIA

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL. I updated the question with a link to the code. I'm trying to the types flowing through.

Comment: Please update your question's title and tags to better represent your question because this is *not* JavaScript.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert your Flow code to TypeScript? Or pure vanilla JS? Because JavaScript doesn't have generics...

Comment: TypeScript has `keyof` to constrain generic type arguments to known keys, however I don't believe TypeScript lets you equate a `keyof` type to a string-enum. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the generic in my first function and changing the param to an object.

```js
function getAudienceHelper(defintions: any) {
  return function<Key>(
    prioritisedAudiences: Key[],
    ...

  ) {
      ...
  }
}
```

When the inner function gets called the generic `Key` is initialised and this will be inferred and map to the `AUDIENCE_DEFS` that gets passed around internally. See [demo code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCArgCYCWuAdgMa4AiuUAzmALxgDeYqYhAqnQCSAUQByAYWEB9AIwAuME3QAnMpQDmAGh78hYyVIBMCpao2oAvqlTU4lJbpETpdYQDEAyguLkqtBsxsnNy8BAJOBvJgAOQAhqQUNLiy0dqh4frSxjHxvklG0ZbWWHiECX64ANK4mEEAJNWYTAA8JbhwUI6ZUq6eAHwA3NZQRDToZHZgJLgAtnAASrgAjkS4SgAUAJScOrzKuOhEypRgAArKcDNkTLgAdPtMcDAAbrjrANpx5fmGqTnftBSAF1NkMrKgRmMJicZrFsD5ErQACpwRrNRp9da5RG4EwqNRaKaMNRkcZ2JgKLjvRpAvFmdRgCybBQAfkaO14vFs9nQYDU0wAHkEAPIAIwAVrhqOhbs9YjBVkx1tMoCSyfZNrd+bgBcKoFiAbhQbswPtDscwGLJdLbgBrGpKlVq6FMTbvbUCoFg4ajaXQsDqA7nCaqcY3EgIiromqYk3YVRwUPXXARw0UsCNd5AtKc7EVdOxSiYHO8J2UUkuylgak1WmKfEaRmoZlgNk1Dmc7kOPNJJgAWTheBIQR7tCYt1h2ANeVobD6YEnkaSKMa05xmiJqvL6tdxs5poORxO8ZDFfDS7Hty3JHWJ8TpMwF-wrD6Jv3o7WA+wQ6v-LXFTnMAPzYVh2DvUNH0NTYTWNcFgGAMBxCOVQUzASE-UmNQwBWNZ1QhX11QDA4nwACVwGA8GUZViW3StOCZDs9kPC10PVaNMFjfd93As8UyfdNM2zN9OSgRNaFTGdcVbUwCRLLjA3QOhYnQWIABlYkwXBlAULZAPOS5k2aFkZI0LN53YaY5kWHClBghR9KuG4jIxRiuLITp1lE5RxKfbYOGEriD3NE4HOTe41ieV51kXQ0VxqdjMS8nzDQ3MsK3JTY90CxkwHIm5XOyoKjyIxTlLUjStK2ALCrAW50AACyof9e0AhTg3vMM+MNW8EyTc80w3D8mFSmj0o1aCauy25qGU6h6vWXSXzAUYyxTLLAqsfcLG9DAcHwJ8lJU5pxDsVV1HM4JuTO1kTsoM6N2uVS4FicgNAUUU4CeXBC0ZIZUHgsAYDUfAADZDDAABaMBsFiJgWCwsI9GcHp3A8IDKGHBr9sNdkEDIGAYDAUV8DUKAtP2Yd-oQ2GwCxojKC0shqAzds2jABBGpOZ15WTYdJiBhmwAAdkMfCoUmIgblIz7bXYjdbrOw7Ynl06yHUKsa0wOsFbVpXGU4zkVXiGB0B19XENV9QlbknjOpIM2FDNuSFKfBQEvWarbd5-iFEEuT9ySrrJNZEz1BgvSLkc3BnJjIIXcNMiKMqxGIhcVHNjkwOJJxEOGzDlsDrK47LaV+d-JNAG6DgNYgKJ316rADp6yIKBOlFIheUEMAZv2ICPo72nGtpvamGsfcu15L3+skgSaizEUJSlGV7SaHrTzts3jRNCfFAOM29fYZraFZRoNyutXHctltnjgMhhyWjhtrHzl48k92p6DnFhrQsTP4qCappY0oEfZ884bimxLmVEBG4P72yvgAwK01ZrzUWvOKA8obhb33ADNwsR7RFWOM-JiwVLqWwUCtGiKYHpMCei9AkCh0EwHyk-CwQA).

```js
const innerFunction = getAudienceHelper(AUDIENCE_DEFS);

innerFunction<AudienceKey>(prioritisedAudiences, ...)
```